# How can I use a look after to match either a single or a double quote?

Tags: regex, grep, gnu

I have a series of strings I want to extract:

```
hello.this_is("bla bla bla")
some random text
hello.this_is('hello hello')
other stuff
```

What I need to get (from many files, but this is not important here) is the content between `hello.this_is(` and `)`, so my desired output is:

```
bla bla bla
hello hello
```

As you see, the text within parentheses can be enclosed with either double or single quotes.

If this was only single quotes I would use a look behind and look ahead just like this:

```
grep -Po "(?<=hello.this_is\(').*(?=')" file
#                            ^      ^
# returns ---> hello hello
```

Similarly, to get strings from double quotes I would say:

```
grep -Po '(?<=hello.this_is\(").*(?=")' file
#                            ^      ^
# returns ---> bla bla bla
```

However, I want to match both cases, so it gets both single and double quotes. I tried with using `$''` to escape, but could not make it work:

```
grep -Po '(?<=hello.this_is\($'["\']').*(?=$'["\']')' file
#                            ^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^
```

I can of course use the ASCII number and say:

```
grep -Po '(?<=hello.this_is\([\047\042]).*' file
```

but I would like to use the quotes and single quotes, since `047` and `042` are not that much representative to me as single and double quotes are.

Comment: If this is Python, you need to account for `r"..."`, `u'...'`, `r'''...'''`, `r"""...."""`, etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it is. In this specific case all strings are only enclosed by a single - single or double quote (that is, no `'''`), without any formatter. In any case, good to take into account if the problem gets bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The `sed` command at the bottom of this answer works only as long as your strings are nice behaving strings like

```
"foo"
```

or

```
'bar'
```

As soon as your strings start to misbehave :) like:

```
"hello \"world\""
```

it won't work any more.

Your input looks like source code. For a stable solution I recommend to use a parser for that language to extract the strings.

---

For trivial use cases:

You can use `sed`. The solution is supposed to work on any POSIX platform in contrast to `grep -oP` which only works with GNU grep:

```
sed -n 's/hello\.this_is(\(["'\'']\)\([^"]*\)\(["'\'']\).*/\2/gp' file
#                                    ^^^^^^^^              ^^
#                                          capture group 2 ^
```

Comment: Nice one! So the key here is doing `["'\'']`. That is, closing the single quote and then adding `\'`, to finally open the single quote again. Cool to see your sed-fu again!

Comment: Nice to meat you again! :) Moved the `^^^^` s to the right position, I hope that's ok (and intended). Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Of course! I added it to point where the capture group is, since it is difficult to see. My mistake makes it clear it is hard

Comment: To be fair, this would also match `"foo'`. Things like `"foo\"bar\""` will get extremely hard to match (if not impossible?)..

Comment: I am facing a similar problem based on this original question! If you want to have a look it is in [How can you match everything up to the next captured group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57819083/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui Hey, nice to meet you :) Will look later, having a training class today

Comment: Oh, cool! It finally was a duplicate of a common problem (facepalm).

Answer (score 1):

Use a capturing group and look for its content like the following:

```
grep -Po 'hello\.this_is\(([\047"])((?!\1).|\\.)*\1\)' file
```

This cares about escaped characters too e.g. `hello.this_is("bla b\"la bla")`

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/eXkdAZ/2)

If the output should be what comes between parentheses then utilize both `\K` and a positive lookahead:

```
grep -Po 'hello\.this_is\(([\047"])\K((?!\1).|\\.)*(?=\1\))' file
```

Outputs:

```
bla bla bla
hello hello
```

Comment: Uhms, this is clever! It would fail if we had something like `hello.this_is(XhelloX)`, but since this is Python code it won't happen :)

Comment: Please see the edit. I replaced `(.)` with `([\047"])`.

Comment: Well the difficulty lies in using `'` and `"` instead of 047 and 042, since they collide with the two possible enclosing characters for a command. Still, I really +1 for the idea of the capturing group here.

Comment: I think you missed my last edit before posting your comment. Also I added a complementary approach.

Answer (score 1):

Based on revo and hek2mgl excellent answers, I ended up using `grep` like this:

```
grep -Po '(?<=hello\.this_is\((["'\''])).*(?=\1)' file
```

Which can be explained as:

- `grep`
- `-Po` use Perl regexp machine and just prints the matches
- `'(?<=hello\.this_is\((["'\''])).*(?=\1)'` the expression

  - `(?<=hello\.this_is\((["'\'']))` look-behind: search strings preceeded by "hello.this_is(" followed by either `'` or `"`. Also, capture this last character to be used later on.
  - `.*` match everything...
  - `(?=\1)` until the captured character (that is, either `'` or `"`) appears again.

The key here was to use `["'\'']` to indicate either `'` or `"`. By doing `'\''` we are closing the enclosing expression, populating with a literal `'` (that we have to escape) and opening the enclosing expression again.