# How can you match everything up to the next captured group?

Tags: regex, grep, gnu

This is a follow up of my previous question [How can I use a look after to match either a single or a double quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55504747/1983854). Say we have a Python file with this content:

```
hello.this_is("bla bla bla")
some random text
hello.this_is('hello hello')  hello.this_is("bla")
hello.this_is("1hello")  hello.this_is("2hello")
other stuff
```

I want to extract all the strings within quotes in `hello.this_is(`, either single or double quotes, so my output is like:

```
bla bla bla
hello hello
bla
1hello
2hello
```

From the answers on the other question I ended up having this expression:

```
grep -Po '(?<=hello\.this_is\((["'\''])).*(?=\1)' file
```

Which works well... unless there are two matches of `hello.this_is()` in the same line and using the same kind of quotes. In that case, the output is like:

```
bla bla bla
hello hello
bla
1hello")  hello.this_is("2hello    # this is wrong
```

That is, the `.*(?=\1)` is a greedy match, so it matches until the last occurrence of the captured group happens again, instead of matching two different patterns.

How can I change the regex in Grep so that it matches everything up to the next captured group in a non greedy way?

To have a very simplified example, it would be like if we want to get all the numbers between the "hello" text in "hello23hello24hello25". Ideally you would get "23" and "24", but instead I get:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=(hello)).+(?=\1)' <<< "hello23hello24hello25"
23hello24
```

Using a more representative example, let's say we use the capture group to match either "hello" or "hillo" in this example:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=(hello|hillo)).+(?=\1)' <<< "hello23hello24hello25hillo26hillo27"
23hello24
26
```

While the desired output would be "23", "24", "26".

I was thinking of replacing the `.+` pattern with something like `[^\1]+` so it matches everything but the captured group... but it does not work.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/NW98tx/1

Comment: Oh man, all of this for just a `?`. Thanks @Wiktor, I thought I had already addressed the greediness while researching, but now I notice I hadn't entirely.

Comment: Yes, it is the most frequent regex question on SO. Also, `[^\1]+` is not negating Group 1 value, to match any text that does not match the start of the Group 1 value you may use `(?:(?!\1).)+`.

Comment: @fedorqui You can parse the python file into an ast. This is a nice blog article about this: https://suhas.org/function-call-ast-python/

Comment: @hek2mgl that's a nice article! I have worked a bit with ast and it is great to go beyond `json.loads()` for strange parsing cases. Thanks for sharing.